# Enumerable.Aggregate error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Everything worked fine until sequentce with the only element was passed to this function. The simplest way to reproduce is:

```
var sumOfSquares = Enumerable.Range(5, 1).Aggregate((s, i) => s + i*i);
// sumOfSquares == 5
```

I think this version of Aggregate should throw an Exception in case when sequence contains only one element. 
Am I right or there is some details I missed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another overload where you can provide an appropriate seed and obtain what I think is your desired result.

```
var sumOfSquares = Enumerable.Range(5, 1).Aggregate(0, (s, i) => s + i * i);
```

In this code, 0 is the initial seed, `s` is the accumulated value, `i` is the current item. This produces the value 25. `(5, 2)` produces 61, `(5, 3)` produces 110, etc.

Answer (score 7):

That shouldn't fail. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx):

> The first element of source is used as the initial aggregate value.

So in this case you just get the first element back (5) and no aggregations are performed. There is no error.

As Anthony Pegram pointed out there is [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) where you can specify the seed value for the aggregation. Setting the seed to 0 gives you the answer 25 which is probably what you want.

```
var sumOfSquares = Enumerable.Range(5, 1).Aggregate(0, (s, i) => s + i * i);
```

And here of course you shouldn't use Aggregate - you can use Sum instead.

```
var sumOfSquares = Enumerable.Range(5, 1).Sum(i => i * i);
```

I guess though that it was just a simplified example.

Comment: Actually the answer would be 0 + 5 * 5 = 25

Comment: @juharr: My answer was wrong before. I've updated it after checking the documentation.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Not very nice, to more or less copy Anthony Pegrams answer.

Comment: @VVS, in the spirit of providing complete answers, it's quite OK. In this case, he's providing the reason for the observed behavior as well as adding information for getting the desired behavior. If Mark's answer is either (a) the highest voted or (b) the accepted answer, it will bubble to the top. By incorporating elements from my answer, it makes it more complete and more useful to subsequent viewers.

Comment: It is not obvious that no aggregations are performed. Actually, to get the correct results, this method can only be used for sequences with 2 or more results. So, I think it misguides a little because it has "unsafe" behavior.

Comment: @Mad, using the first overload, your "desired" behavior wouldn't even be met for sequences with more than 1 item. `(5, 2)` would produce 5 + 6 * 6, which is 41. But I agree that the behavior isn't quite as intuitive as you might think, but I also agree with Mark that more appropriate methods are available to perform the given function.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: +1 for your answer and I've now added a credit to you in mine. I would have added credit sooner, but I was rushing a bit to fix up my answer after realizing it was wrong (the long time it took me to fix the answer was due to real-life interrupting just after I submitted the first version). Thanks for your rational response to VVS, +1 for that! I'll find a couple of your older answers to +1 too so you get some rep from the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why should it? It is perfectly valid to take the sum of a single number.

Also, for the caller to avoid the exception, he would need to do something like this:

```
public double MySum(IEnumerable<double> seq) {
    switch (seq.Count()) {
        case 0: return 0.0;
        case 1: return seq.First();
        default: return seq.Aggregate((s, i) => s + i);
    }
}
```

A whole lot of calls, which also needs to pass through the sequence twice (or at least the 2 first elements).

Comment: Just imagine, you have created an aggregaion function and pass it to Aggregate. `sequence.Aggregate(SomeFunction)` and all works fine for 1 item length. Then, in example, after some days you modify SomeFunction. What should you do ? You MUST find all references to SomeFunction and fix them because because of Aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide a seed (see Anthony Pegram's answer for an excellent example) then the `Aggregate` function does almost nothing to an IEnumerable with only one item.  The first element in the sequence becomes the seed, and with no additional items in your IEnumerable, what is it going to do?  Thus, without a seed specified, the `Aggregate` function will return the value of the first element.  You can really see it in work with the following code that compiles and runs:

```
var c = 0;
var result = Enumerable.Range(5,1).Aggregate((acc,x) => acc + (x / c));
//result == 5
```

Change that to `Enumerable.Range(5,2)` and it immediately throws a 'divide by zero' error.

**Reference**: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) in the 'Remarks' section

Comment: ...And Mark updates his answer 40 seconds before I can post mine...such is life! ^_^

Comment: Actually, MSDN should tell us something like: "This method works by calling func one time for each element in source except cases when there are one or zero elements in the sequence."

Comment: @Mad Hollander Agreed.  They could certainly be a bit clearer about the 'special cases' of the function.